# Lower bound for character sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Hello

Let $p$ be a prime number. According to Davenport (Multiplicative Number Theory, page 137) Schur proved (Indeed he proved much more, but let consider the simplest case)
$$
\max_{t}\left|\sum_{n\leq t}\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)\right|>\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2\pi}.
$$ 
What can we say about $t$ which we obtain the maximum? In other words, can we find $t\gg p^{\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon}$ such that 
$$
\left|\sum_{n\leq t}\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)\right|>\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2\pi}.
$$

Comment: Are you sure you want to write $\gg$ (large $t$) rather than $\ll$?

Comment: Burgess proved the character sum is $O(p^{3/16} t^{1/2} \log p)$, so if it's $\gg p^{1/2}$ then $t \gg p^{5/8 - \epsilon}$.

Comment: Fedja@: Yes. I am sure I want $\gg$.

Comment: Even if it were possible to have $t \ll p^{1/2 + \epsilon}$ then $p-t$ would work too and satisfy $t \gg p^{1/2 + \epsilon}$ by a wide margin...

Answer (score 2):

The character sum you ask about is $\gg \sqrt{p}$ for at least one value of $n$. I learned the following slick proof from [a paper of Leo Goldmakher](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.5547v2): We have

$$\tau(p) = \sum_{n \leq p} \bigg( \frac{n}{p} \bigg) e^{2 \pi i n/p}$$ and that is a Gauss sum with absolute value $\sqrt{p}$... now use partial summation.

In addition, there is an infinite family of characters for which the lower bound may be multiplied by an additional fractional power of $\log \log p$. A result like this was first proved by Paley. Please see the paper I linked to for proofs and references to earlier work.